# Save data into one field database from multiple combobox in vb

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox, insert

i want to ask how to save into 1 field database from multiple combobox in VB

1. i have 3 combo box : cboDate, CboMonth, cboYear.
2. cboDate has data : 1 - 31
3. cboMonth has data : January - December
4. cboYear has data : 1960 - now

and when i insert to database it will insert only in 1 field, Field "date_insert" with format date in DBS, ah iam using sql server

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use a `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: i dont know why but in my VB there is no command for datetimepicker

Comment: Create an instance of the DateTime structure in your vb.net based on the values the user selected in the combobox and send that to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

First, Declare a `DateTime` Variable, say Dt

`Dim Dt as DateTime`

Then get the selected data from 3 combos and convert it into DateTime

`Dt=Cdate(cboYear.SelectedItem.toString & "-" & cboMonth.SelectedItem.toString & "-" & cboDate.SelectedItem.toString)`

Now you can store the Dt's Value in database.